# Solace JMS queue: search and process message

Tags: jms, solace

Could I search any particular message in solace JMS queue and then process in prior to other messages? Do we have such functionality w.r.t to solace queue.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such a functionality to search a solace queue for messages. These are designed for messages to be processed in the order in which the are received.

You can use a QueueBrowser to get a static snapshot of the messages and process those messages you want prior to others. Using selectors might help too, if it is applicable for your search use-case. But only the native Java implementation of the Solace API can delete messages; a JMS QueueBrowser doesn't provide that.